# Segfault when dereferencing pointer to pointer within struct

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a structure which includes a pointer to a pointer as one of its members. I keep getting a segfault when trying to dereference this pointer.

Create a person in `person_init` and give it a name (John). Name is a pointer to a character string. I can `printf()` no problem in this function. Returning to the `main()` function, again I can `printf()` the name no problem. But then when
I enter a new function and try to `printf()` I get a segfault. I'm really confused because I'm pretty sure `name` is being allocated on the heap.

What am I missing here?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* structure with a pointer to pointer member */
struct person {
    char **name;
};


/* allocate space for the strucutre */
int person_init(struct person **p)
{
    struct person *newp = malloc(sizeof(struct person));

    /* give a name, allocated on the heap */
    char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    *name = 'J';
    *(name + 1) = 'o';
    *(name + 2) = 'h';
    *(name + 3) = 'n';
    *(name + 4) = '\0';
    newp->name = &name;
    *p = newp;

    printf("Name in init: %s\n", *(*p)->name); /* this works */

    return 0;
}


void print_name(struct person *p)
{
    printf(*p->name);
}


int main()
{
    struct person *person;
    person_init(&person);
    printf("Name in main: %s\n", *person->name);   /* works */
    print_name(person);                            /* segfault */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
newp->name = &name;
```

`newp->name` now points to `name`, which is a local variable in `person_init`. As soon as `person_init` returns, `name` is gone and `newp->name` is an invalid pointer. Any attempt to use it afterwards results in undefined behavior.

Fix:

```
struct person {
    char *name;
};
```

And initialize it as

```
newp->name = name;
```

Now `newp->name` is a copy of `name`, i.e. it points to the allocated string.